# Fast inserts results in data loss

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange bug here related to mysql and php. I'm wondering if it could be a performance problem on our server's behalf too.

I got a class used to manage rebate promotional codes. The code is great, works fine and doesn exactly what it is supposed to do. The saveChanges() operation sends an INSERT or UPDATE depending on the state of the object and in the current context will only insert cause i'm trying to generate coupon codes.

The classe's saveChanges goes like this: (I know, i shouldn't be using old mysql, but i've got no choice due to architectural limitations of the software, so don't complain about that part please)

```
public function saveChanges($asNew = false){

    //Get the connection
    global $conn_panier;

    //Check if the rebate still exists
    if($this->isNew() || $asNew){

        //Check unicity if new
        if(reset(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM panier_rabais_codes WHERE code_coupon = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($this->getCouponCode(), $conn_panier).'"', $conn_panier))) > 0){
            throw new Activis_Catalog_Models_Exceptions_ValidationException('Coupon code "'.$this->getCouponCode().'" already exists in the system', $this, __METHOD__, $this->getCouponCode());
        }

        //Update the existing rebate
        mysql_query($q = 'INSERT INTO panier_rabais_codes 
                        (
                            `no_rabais`,
                            `code_coupon`,
                            `utilisation`,
                            `date_verrou`
                        )VALUES(
                            '.$this->getRebate()->getId().',
                            "'.mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($this->getCouponCode()), $conn_panier).'",
                            '.$this->getCodeUsage().',
                            "'.($this->getInvalidityDate() === NULL ? '0000-00-00 00:00:00' : date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($this->getInvalidityDate()))).'"
                        )', $conn_panier);
        return (mysql_affected_rows($conn_panier) >= 1);

    }else{

        //Update the existing rebate
        mysql_query('UPDATE panier_rabais_codes
                        SET
                            `utilisation` = '.$this->getCodeUsage().',
                            `date_verrou` = "'.($this->getInvalidityDate() === NULL ? '0000-00-00 00:00:00' : date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($this->getInvalidityDate()))).'"
                        WHERE 
                            no_rabais = '.$this->getRebate()->getId().' AND code_coupon = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($this->getCouponCode(), $conn_panier).'"', $conn_panier);
        return (mysql_affected_rows($conn_panier) >= 0);

    }

}
```

So as you can see, the code itself is pretty simple and clean and returns true if the insert succeeded, false if not.

The other portion of the code generates the codes using a random algorithm at goes like this:

```
while($codes_to_generate > 0){

    //Sleep to delay mysql choking on the input
    usleep(100);

    //Generate a random code
    $code = strtoupper('RC'.$rebate->getId().rand(254852, 975124));
    $code .= strtoupper(substr(md5($code), 0, 1));
    $rebateCode = new Activis_Catalog_Models_RebateCode($rebate);
    $rebateCode->setCouponCode($code);
    $rebateCode->setCodeUsage($_REQUEST['utilisation_generer']);
    try{
        if($rebateCode->saveChanges()){
            $codes_to_generate--;
            $generated_codes[] = $code;
        }
    }catch(Exception $ex){
    }

}
```

As you can see here, two things to note. The number of codes to generate and the array of generated codes only get filled if i get a return true from the saveChanges, so mysql HAS to report that the information was inserted for this part to happen.

Another tidbit is the first line of the while:

```
//Sleep to delay mysql choking on the input
usleep(100);
```

Wtf? Well this post is all about this. My code works flawlessly with small amounts of codes to generate. But if i ask mysql to save more than a few codes at once, i have to throttle myself using usleep or mysql drops some of these lines. It will report that there are affected rows but is not saving them.

Under 100 lines, i don't need throttling and then i need to usleep depending on the amount of lines to insert. It must be something simple but i don't know what. Here is a sum of the lines i tried to insert and the minimum usleep throttle i had to implement:

- < 100 lines: none
- < 300 lines: 2 ms
- < 1000 lines: 5 ms
- < 2000 lines: 10 ms
- < 5000 lines: 20 ms
- < 10000 lines: 100 ms

Thank you for your time

Comment: You are not catching errors after your queries. Wouldn't that be the first step to take to get clarity about what is happening?

Comment: Sorry i already did that, no errors

Comment: So the code you are actually using is different from what you have posted? The real code checks for errors after every query? Why not post that code then

Comment: Like i said, the code works perfectly fine, it's a mysql problem but i tag it php just to see if there is something i can add to slow down the process or throttle correctly

Comment: No i USED to check them cause i thought it could be an error, but there aren't errors at all so i removed it.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin -- Pekka means that it could be the queries themselves erroring out.  At some point if MySQL throws an error owing to an IO problem or other, you would see what it is if you handle errors properly in code.

Comment: Well there are no errors and it doesn't make sense to have errors or mysql_affected_rows wouldn't return 1 and thus i wouldn't return true to my generation code...

Comment: Checking for errors by testing for the `mysql_query()` result and looking at the output of `mysql_error()` is the first step in debugging, and should be present in every piece of code using the mySQL lubrary.  You may well be right that the problem is elsewhere, but I don't see the point in guessing what's happening here when the most basic  of checks are not in place.

Comment: Ok, whatever, pass on to another question buddy, you're looking at the wrong problem, i had a ECHO MYSQL_ERROR($conn_panier) in my code before and nothing was outputted anywhere, read the post completly, try to make some sense of it all instead of bullshitting useless comments

Comment: @Michael fair enough, you're right - if you're checking for `mysql_affected_rows` being > 0, it should indeed work (as it'll return -1 if the last query failed). The worst that can happen is false negatives, but you claim there are none. You may need to take a look at mySQL's logs then, see whether there's something in there - data shouldn't just vanish... Bear in mind what @moechofe says below though

Comment: @Pekka It could be considered as a false positive that my logic was wrong and going into the UPDATE portion instead of the INSERT. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your codes are all inserted and not updated, because, update a non existing line does nothing.

Comment: You got it, it was that, the "isNew()" checked to see if the code already existed, and since updating can result in 0 rows updated when the key exists and no data was changed, the update always resulted in TRUE storing the code as added instead of updated. I forced my saveChanges(true) instead to force an insert and now it throws an exception that i bypass when code exists forcefully generating the codes correctly.